# How to pass command line arguments in IPython jupyter notebook

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, ipython, argparse

I a  new to Ipython. Currently i have installed Ipython using Anaconda and writing a code to plot chart using jupyter notebook UI. 
I want to pass few arguments to my working script with the help of argparse module. 
below is the code..

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Process display arguments')
parser.add_argument('-t', "--test_name", help="Mandatory test name directory path", type=str)
parser.add_argument('-s', "--symbolSet", nargs = '?', help="Optional symbolset", const = 'baz', default = 'deafultOne')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.test_name is None:
        print("test_name argument is mandatory.. Use option -h for help.. Exiting..")
        sys.exit(1)
```

Now how can I pass these arguments while executing my script through UI or can I run my script through command prompt and still be able to draw the chart?
I am working on windows machine. Please let me know if you need more info. on this.

Comment: Add at `print(args)` statement so you can see what you `parse_args()` produces.  It can also be handy add `import sys` and `print(sys.argv)` to see what the parser has to work with.  That said, does this work with called as a plain `python` script?  Or with plain `ipython`?

Comment: When you start `jupyter` you give commands to the server, not the notebook itself.  I think it's been discussed before, but can't a match yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38755864/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534440/passing-command-line-arguments-to-argv-in-jupyter-ipython-notebook

Comment: So I don't have any alternative? Is it not possible to draw the chart using Ipython  notebook UI & simultaneously passing the the arguments to the script?

Comment: There are ways to do it, but still klunky, I agree. E.g. you can pass parameters via environmental variables. Or you can export your notebook into a python file, and run that file, which can generate the chart as a file or in a popup window. And the second response by hpaulj links to this intriguing solution: [Allow arguments to be passed to notebooks via URL or command line](https://gist.github.com/gbishop/acf40b86a9bca2d571fa)