# how to implement command line argument in google colabortary?

Tags: python, command-line, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I tried to implement command-line argument in python,

```
# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,
    help="path to input dataset")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--plot", type=str, default="plot.png",
    help="path to output loss/accuracy plot")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", type=str,
    default="mask_detector.model",
    help="path to output face mask detector model")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

**Error**

usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] -d DATASET [-p PLOT] [-m MODEL]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: -d/--dataset
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2

Comment: if you set -d as required you must supply it when you run your code

Comment: I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823991/argparse-in-ipython-notebook-unrecognized-arguments-f) helps. I'm not closing just in case.

Comment: It's kind of obvious from the error message: your tool invocation did not include a command line option -d with a value. Try printing `sys.argv` before invoking `parse_args`, to see what made it from the invocation to the options processor.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this(just put the '!' before the command on any new file and put the path of your script file and dataset in the command )

```
!python  '/content/drive/My Drive/face-mask-detector/train_mask_detector.py' --dataset  '/content/drive/My Drive/face-mask-detector/dataset'
```